# How can I format the date time field as per the desired output?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, griddb

I'm working with GridDB for a sensor sales department project, I've a orders datamodel, this model contains order details of different order purchased each day like vision or control sensor with their order_id, order_name, sensor_id, customer_id, product_name, sales_person, order_date, price.

I have a customer datamodel contain - customer_id, order_id(foreign_key), customer_name, total_order_purchased, product_name, total_sales
I want to display all the customers who have purchased any sort of sensors after May, 2019 including order_id corresponding to customers details. Since i have a order_date field as datetime timestamp field so i want my output to look like

| Customer_name | Order_date |
| --- | --- |
| Mr.John | May, 2019 |
| Mr.Smith | May, 2019 |

So as you can notice I want my date to be formatted like above how to do this in GridDB?

I was trying to search this on google but couldn't get a solution yet.

Comment: Why did you tag mysql? This question seems not to mention MySQL, and any solution for MySQL may not work in GridDB.